# Simple sum function in Haskell from Graham Hutton's "Programming in Haskell" not working

Tags: haskell

On the first code example in "Programming in Haskell" the following is stated:

> Recall the function sum used earlier in this chapter, which produces
> the sum of a list of numbers. In Haskell, sum can be defined using two
> equations:
>
> ```
> sum [] = 0      
> sum (n:ns) = n + sum ns
> ```

Immediately, this code fails both in the ghci interpreter and upon compilation with the error: "Non-exhaustive patterns in function sum"

After further research it seems this is because the case of a single number isn't covered. What gets me is the next few examples in the book also fail to work.

Am I missing something here? The book was released rather recently in 2016 and I can't find anyone else complaining aout this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you enter the first clause of the definition of `sum` and press enter GHCI assume that you've finished and it should evaluate the program. The program

```
sum [] = 0
```

Doesn't specify what to do if the argument is non-empty, so you get the "non-exhaustive patterns" error.

GHCI has `:{` and `:}` commands to allow you to enter multiple clauses (or other code that spans multiple lines:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| sum [] = 0
Prelude| sum (n:ns) = n + sum ns
Prelude| :}
Prelude> sum []
0
Prelude>
```

In general I would recommend saving the definitions you are working with in a file and loading that file in GHCI. Then you can `:reload` when you make some changes and call your function/s with various arguments to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it for the ghci interpreter. How do I do the :{ }: equivalent in a file? It's not allowing that syntax there and omitting it results in the same error.

Comment: The code in your OP should work absolutely fine if loaded from a file. Please share the exact contents of the file.

Comment: @RobinZigmond You were right. I think the problem was that I was adding a print statement, or trying to view the output. I understand that may be a side effect, but how would I execute the script to do that? It works within a main = do declaration at the top of the file, but then it seems I need to use "let" before all functions, and then the sum [] breaks down again? Or could I print it without needing to do main = do?

Comment: @user4779 (1/2) I think you may be a bit confused about what you put in a file. A Haskell file just contains a list of functions (plus possibly some import statements and a module header) — [here’s an example](https://github.com/bradrn/pls-mgr/blob/34462da8fc7faf5f7b2e46766e271298a95070a0/src/Parser.hs) from my own code. You can load this file into GHCi using the `:load` command, after which you can call the functions from GHCi.

Comment: @user4779 (2/2) If one of your functions is called `main`, then when you compile your code with GHC, the resulting standalone executable will start by automatically calling `main`. However, if you load that file into GHCi, then `main` will just be another function. Note that `main` is defined the same way as all other functions, and as such, it shouldn’t have an impact on the syntax you use to define your other functions. (Of course, you can use `let` to define your function _within_ `main`, but that’s different to what you want to do.)

Comment: @bradrn Thanks that makes sense. So is my understanding right, if I want to compile and run a program I put the logic in main, but if I just want to declare functions and manually run them in the ghci interpreter I put them outside main? A question then in terms of putting things inside "main". In my original question how would I then run a program such as sum [] = 0; sum (n:ns) = n + sum ns? I can see how to do this in the interpreted but not within main.

Comment: @user4779 (1/2) There’s no reason why you can’t do both! Many Haskell programs — probably the vast majority of them, in fact — implement the overall control flow of the program in `main`, but then call out to other functions for the actual logic. For instance, the `main` function of my program [here](https://github.com/bradrn/Conkey/blob/49963cf831f8aaaa5eae7b5ceb853be00a5bbcda/ms2mim/app/Main.hs) just outlines the overall processing — open a file, parse it, convert it, render it to text and then save the result…

Comment: @user4779 (2/2) …while calling functions such as `parse`, `convert` and `render` (defined elsewhere) for the actual logic. This lets me keep my code readable, ensures a nice separation of concerns between the functions, and lets me test the various parts (each of which corresponds to a function) separately in GHCi while still letting me run the whole executable.

Comment: @user4779 (And by the way, when using GHCi, `main` is just a function like all the others — there’s no reason why you can’t load your module and then call `main` from GHCi, although in practise you don’t often need to do that. However, as I already implied, it’s generally considered good practise to structure your program using many small functions rather than one large function. One reason for this is that you can then test each small function in GHCi if you need to, while you can’t easily test a part of a large monolithic `main` function.)

Comment: @bradrn Wow. Please write a book seriously if you haven't already. You give such rich, to the point knowledge that is incredibly useful that I couldn't find anywhere else. I was completely confused but I I get it now from your few comments. Thanks!

Comment: You’re very welcome @user4779! I‘m glad I could help. (But I don’t think I could write a book about it, although it’s very nice of you to say I should! I have a lot to learn about this stuff as well, and what I said earlier is just what I’ve picked up from my programming experience so far.)